# Memory Used On global_status mariadb

Tags: mariadb, information-schema

on mariadb at `information_schema.global_status` they have variable name  `memory_used` in bytes
this is actual memory use from mariadb ?

edit add example case

on my servers i have `threads_running=10` and `memory_used=2666` on MB so total 26 GB
but when run command `free -mh` is 89 gb
with configuration

```
...    
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 70G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 70
innodb_log_file_size = 8G
...
```

Comment: I checked several servers; a typical value is about 1% or RAM, which is _much_ less than the usage.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-status-variables/#memory_used says "Global or per-connection memory usage, in bytes."   400MB is the median, which does not compute as per-connection.

Comment: so this variable is accurate for how much mariadb consume memory or RAM ?
because currently I working on make monitoring system like mysql enterprise monitor.

Comment: No.  I can't figure out what it is measuring.  `memory_used` is much too small to be total memory, and much too big to be per-connection.  MariaDB will grow to about 70GB + 1GB.  How much RAM do you have?  Is the dataset big enough to fill 70GB?

Comment: I'm seeing, for example, "Memory_used": 302286904.  Can you supply the things mentioned here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Answer (score 1):

Local testing on toy test instance:

`show global status like 'memory_used'` 276360624

`show session status like 'memory_used';` 69608

Looking the code the "global memory used" is the total of all the per connection memory allocations, but exclude actual global allocations like key_buffer, innodb_buffer_pool etc.

Comment: on this part `show session status like 'memory_used';` they are using bytes or megabyte ?

Comment: bytes, for the current connection only.

Comment: for global memory used is count from threads_connected or threads_running ?

Comment: I'd assume connected because even connected, not running, threads consume memory.

Comment: so currently on `show global status like 'memory_used'` 2692750376 in bytes so in Gb is 2GB. currently i have 850 on `THREAD_CONNECTED`. this is mean on 850 thread connected using 2GB `memory_used` ?